# preg_replace_callback() para remover caracteres que não são dígitos

Tags: php, laravel, regex, preg-replace

Eu utilizo o Laravel e estou tentando utilizar a função `preg_replace_callback()` para remover ponto, vírgula, hífen, traço e barra dos números de CNPJ inseridos no sistema.

Eu utilizei a função `preg_replace_callback()` dessa forma:

```
    function parseTagsRecursive($input)
    {

        $regex = '#[^0-9]#';

        return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'parseTagsRecursive', $input);
    }

    $cnpj = parseTagsRecursive($cnpj);
```

Estou tendo como retorno o seguinte erro:

> preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'parseTagsRecursive&#039

Utilizei o exemplo 3 da [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

De acordo com esse exemplo, estou implementando da maneira correta. Alguém tem alguma dica de como devo proceder?

Tentei também o método preg_replace da seguinte forma:

```
function deixarSomenteDigitos($input) {
        return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);    
    }

    $input['cgc_cl1'] = deixarSomenteDigitos($input['cgc_cl1']);
```

Utilizei um site para gerar um cnpj aleatório para testes. Ele retornou: 70.700.516/0001-24

Ao tratar o campo para salvar no banco, o cnpj foi salvo da mesma forma que entrou.

Alguns pontos a considerar: estou fazendo essas validações dentro de um arquivo FormRequest do Laravel, responsável pelas validações dos dados da minha classe.

Comment: Realmente man precisa ser preg_replace_callback ?? tem algum motivo especifico para usar ele ?

Comment: Eu usava o método preg_replace() mas, parece que foi descontinuado. Eu coloquei ele e não aconteceu simplesmente nada. O número foi salvo com os pontos, vírgulas e barras do mesmo jeito.

Comment: O que foi descontinuado é a função [`ereg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) <- inclusive a documentação recomenda que se use o `preg_replace` no lugar

Comment: De verdade, não está funcionando. Eu usava ele assim:

Comment: $cnpj = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cnpj);

Comment: O que foi descontinuado no `preg_replace` foi o suporte ao [modificador `e`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval), que executava código arbitrário na substituição (e para substituir esse mecanismo específico, recomenda-se o uso de `preg_replace_callback`). Mas a função `preg_replace` em si continua existindo normalmente.

Comment: O que eu devo alterar nesse código da preg_replace então pra ele funcionar?

Comment: @Kênia Estou usando `preg_replace` exatamente como indiquei na minha resposta abaixo e está funcionando. Talvez seja algum problema em outro lugar, pois o `preg_replace` em si está ok. Sugiro vc [edit] a pergunta e colocar o valor exato do CNPJ e o valor que está obtendo com o `preg_replace`, quem sabe assim temos uma pista do que pode ser o seu problema

Comment: Imagino que o problema esteja em outro local então. Vou tentar descobrir aqui.

Comment: A parte específica do `preg_replace` funciona: https://ideone.com/rGbKHt - talvez o problema esteja na hora de salvar no banco (e aí eu não tenho como ajudar mais, pois não conheço o Laravel)

Comment: Mano posta o seu controller ou service do laravel para termos visão de como  você setá salvando pq está muito estranho.

Comment: Resolvido! Eu estava salvando no Request. O Request é só pra validação de dados. Não é possível alterar a escrita dos dados nele. Eu coloquei o preg_replace diretamente no Controller. De toda forma, o tópico serviu para clarear as idéias e eu consegui entender o problema!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você só quer remover tudo que não for números, pode simplesmente usar [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '74.208.285/0001-97'); // 74208285000197
```

No caso, tudo que não for número (`[^0-9]`) é substituído pela string vazia (`''`), ou seja, esses caracteres são removidos, e no final sobram somente os números.

Se quiser, pode criar uma função para isso:

```
function deixarSomenteDigitos($input) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);    
}

echo deixarSomenteDigitos('74.208.285/0001-97'); // 74208285000197
```

---

`preg_replace_callback` é útil quando você precisa manipular os *matches* de alguma maneira não trivial (algo que exija uma função para tal, como nos exemplos citados na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)).

E o exemplo 3 da documentação é mais complexo ainda, porque usa regex recursiva (já que ele está manipulando uma estrutura que pode ser recursiva), e faz as substituições recursivamente também.

Mas esse não é o seu caso, pois você só precisa detectar tudo que não for dígito e remover, então não é necessário um *callback* (e muito menos recursivo).

Comment: Imagino que o problema seja outro então. Pq fiz exatamente como você:

Comment: function deixarSomenteDigitos($input) {
            return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);    
        }

        $cnpj = deixarSomenteDigitos($cnpj);

Comment: E não funciona.

Comment: @Kênia Eu sugiro que vc edite a pergunta e coloque o valor exato do `$cnpj` que está usando e o valor que está obtendo como resultado, quem sabe assim temos uma pista do que pode estar acontecendo